# LINQ Error When using DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to pull down the NULLS of the contacts and I am using DefaultIfEmpty to do it. But I am getting this error.

"The method 'GroupJoin' cannot follow the method 'Join' or is not supported. Try writing the query in terms of supported methods or call the 'AsEnumerable' or 'ToList' method before calling unsupported methods."

I am using the LINQ-to-CRM provider and querying from the CRM 2011 Web Service.

This is the code I am using:

```
var linqQuery = (from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")
         join a in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("account") on ((EntityReference)r["accountid"]).Id equals a["accountid"]
         join c in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") on ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Id equals c["contactid"]
         where ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Id.Equals(new Guid("c55c2e09-a3be-e011-8b2e-00505691002b"))
         select new
         {
           OpportunityId = !r.Contains("opportunityid") ? string.Empty : r["opportunityid"],
           CustomerId = !r.Contains("customerid") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["customerid"]).Name,
           Priority = !r.Contains("opportunityratingcode") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["opportunityratingcode"],
           ContactName = !r.Contains("new_contact") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_contact"]).Name,
           Source = !r.Contains("new_source") ? string.Empty : r["new_source"],
           CreatedOn = !r.Contains("createdon") ? string.Empty : r["createdon"],
           State = !a.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : a["address1_stateorprovince"],
           Zip = !a.Contains("address1_postalcode") ? string.Empty : a["address1_postalcode"],
           Eval = !r.Contains("new_colderevaluation") ? string.Empty : r.FormattedValues["new_colderevaluation"],
           DistributorName = !r.Contains("new_channelpartner") ? string.Empty : ((EntityReference)r["new_channelpartner"]).Name,
           ContactStreetAddress = !c.Contains("address1_line1") ? string.Empty : c["address1_line1"]
         });
```

How would I go about getting rid of this error? Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using?

Comment: I am using the LINQ-to-CRM provider and querying from the CRM 2011 Web Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your LINQ query must ultimately translate to a valid QueryExpression, you can't do some of the fancier projection stuff because the OrganizationDataContext isn't smart enough to run the simple QueryExpression and then apply your fun "`fieldname = !c.Contains("fieldname") ? string.Empty : c["fieldname"]`" in memory.  You have to do that yourself.

So, in your first query, just do:

```
var linqQuery = (from r in orgServiceContext.CreateQuery("opportunity")     
    // snip
    select new
    {
      fieldname = c["fieldname"],
      //etc...
    });
```

Then do something like:

```
var linqQuery2 = from r in linqQuery.ToList()
                 select new
                 {
                   fieldname = r["fieldname"] == null ? string.Empty : r["fieldname"],
                   //(etc)...
                 };
```

Comment: Thanks! So I need to do two queries? How would I make the two queries? Sorry, I'm new to LINQ. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've updated it to make it a little more obvious.  In the first linqQuery, just do simple things that can be converted to FetchXML.  Then in linqQuery2, you are querying from the results of the first linqQuery.  The ToList() is the secret - it forces the first query to run (using FetchXML and OrganizationServiceContext) and then your second query is just happening in memory.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I gave that a try and I get this error: "CS1928: 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments" Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Ah - the .Contains method you are using only works as you expect when it is working against an Entity type object.  Since we are using two queries, the second query is not working against a true Entity but an anonymous type (since you use select new in your first query).  The fix is to not use .Contains in your second query, but just to check for null using normal code.

Comment: Thanks Josh! How would you check for NULLs without using the Contains? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the code above - see second query's select area.  I don't have access to a compiler right now so I'm not positive that it will actually work, but give it a shot.